# What would cause a limit on the length of text that can be drawn with DrawText?

Tags: c, winapi, combobox

I have come up against a problem. I don't seem to be able to draw more than about 4000 characters of a text string with DrawText.

```
case WM_PAINT:
     hps = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps );

     if (pFieldVal)
     {
       int len = strlen(pFieldVal);   /* Variable 'len' only temporary */
     /*if (len > MAX_WIN32_DRAWTEXT)     Code added to protect against */
     /*  len = MAX_WIN32_DRAWTEXT;       disappearing characters!      */

       DrawText( hps,
                 pFieldVal,
                 len,
     (RECT FAR *)&FRect,
                 DT_LEFT | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_NOPREFIX);
     }
```

If I draw a shorter string with the same code, it is fine.

The limit point appears to be around 4094 characters. A string of length 4094 displays fine, whereas one of length 4095 is rendered invisible.

Does anyone have any suggestions what could be causing this short limit?

Comment: Perhaps there's a defect in your code. You didn't show it. Perhaps this really is a limit. All the same, the user can't read it so why bother trying to out so much text in.

Comment: BTW, if you need to associate large data with combobox item you could use CB_SETITEMDATA: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775909(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @DavidHeffernan while it is true the user can't read it, unfortunately that doesn't help me right now. Perhaps in the longer term I will be able to change the way they view this data, but right now I need to understand why I can't see the string when it is longer than 4094 characters. Sorry not to have shown code, I'm not sure what to show in this case, any hints?

Comment: @KonstantinL Thanks for the hint, I'm not sure if I'm understanding it correctly though. Do you think this will allow a string longer than 4094 characters to become visible in the combo-box?

Comment: No. It is only suitable for storing some data. I can't imagine even 1000 symbols wide combobox :) and therefore I assumed you have to store data only, not show it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you report. Perhaps my code is different from yours. How could I tell? You decided to conceal your code instead of providing a [mcve].

Comment: I am not trying to conceal my code, I just struggled to know what within it to show to demonstrate, since I don't know where the limit would be. Have I created the class wrong, have I added the strings wrong, and so on. If it helps I can add code. Do you have some suggestion (as already requested) on what code I should show?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you for letting me know that it is possible to show >4094 characters in a combo-box - that is very good to know! I found it very difficult to believe that I was the first person to notice this. Surely someone else would have found it. I will try to reduce my code down to produce an example to demonstrate it, to see where our code differs.

Comment: I have started back from first principals and proved to myself that you can indeed show > 5000 characters in a combo-box. Within the application that is showing the errant behaviour, I see the problem in a combo-box, and edit box and in fact just in a basic DrawText. I don't think the problem is within the DrawText code itself since the same code works with shorter strings, but I have updated the question accordingly. There must be something affecting the code elsewhere that is having an impact. I would show that code too, but I don't know which code to show.

Comment: @MoragHughson Can you pass `-1` to the `nCount` (3rd) parameter of `DrawTextA` and see if it fixes your issue? According to MSDN, passing `-1` allows DrawTextA to determine the length of the string to display on its own.

Comment: `strlen(pFieldVal)` - so you are using ANSI character encoding in your application. That implies, that `DrawText` will have to convert the input string to Unicode first, before calling into the wide character API. Could you try using wide character strings (`wchar_t` in place of `char`) as well as calling the wide character version of the API (`DrawTextW`)?

Comment: @Entry0x8 Until I discovered the problem, I did have -1 in there. The len variable was only introduced to work-around this. :-(

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the suggestion, I will try that out.